# Css line-clamp ellipsis raised for certain fonts

Tags: css, google-fonts

Using Gothic A1 Google Font and line-clamp css property, ellipsis are raised. With all others font they are baseline.

How can I make them baseline also with Gothic A1 font?

https://codepen.io/textarea/pen/wvvmGOr

```
.box {
  font-family: 'Gothic A1', sans-serif;
  width: 500px;
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Opened a github issue here https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/2298, but it seems there is no chance on this font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and found that the issue is solved by using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gothic+A1:wght@100;200;300;400;700;800;900&amp;display=swap">` on the document head (or import it on the css file). It uses many different files and unicode ranges, so if you are self hosting you have to download all the files in the link and use their font-face style. If anyone has a better solution, please share.

Answer (score 3):

You can override ellipsis charter with this code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ellipsis';
  src: local('Arial');
  unicode-range: U+2026;
}
```

and then add `font-family: 'Ellipsis', 'Gothic A1';` to text block.

[full example](https://codepen.io/mavajee/pen/ExPRgRG).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here and...
trying the font samples in fonts.google.com I realised that this is a strange font feature.

Ellipsis is always rendered vertically centered with Gothic A1 font.

The solution could be to use three dots (...) instead an ellipsis character (…), or use another font.

[image: Here you can see an screen capture of how ellipsis is showed in the Google fonts sample text]

Comment: There is no option to change ellipsis charachter in line-clamp properties.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation at work. We are using Meiryo font which is geared more for Kanji (Japanese and Chinese) characters. In Japanese and Chinese language the ellipsis is centered in the line rather than aligned to the baseline like most Western languages. I have read that Gothic font is a popular choice in Japan and China. Maybe this helps explain the issue with Gothic font as well.